# showing scale of dendrogram in R when using aheatmap/heatmap2

Tags: r, cluster-analysis, hierarchical-clustering

How can I make it so R plots the dendrogram scale (so that the height of each dendrogram can be interpreted) along with the heatmap when calling NMF package `aheatmap` or `heatmap.2`? These dendrograms show the scale: http://gastonsanchez.com/blog/how-to/2012/10/03/Dendrograms.html
This is the default behavior of doing `plot(hclust(...))` and I'd like to emulate that but not sure how to do it via `heatmap` functions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue here is how `heatmap.2` plots a `dendrogram` object. `heatmap.2` uses the code `plot(ddr, horiz = TRUE, axes = TRUE, yaxs = "i", leaflab = "none")`, where `ddr` is the dendrogram. You want the `axes` argument to be `FALSE`. As a workaround, I created a modified version of the `heatmap.2` function. See `?plot.dendrogram` for more information.

```
x = matrix( rnorm(25), ncol=5 )
f = gplots:::heatmap.2

# Edit the appropriate lines of the heatmap.2 function
print(body(f)[[75]]) # The line to edit
# if (dendrogram %in% c("both", "row")) {
#   plot(ddr, horiz = TRUE, axes = FALSE, yaxs = "i", leaflab = "none")
# } else plot.new()
body(f)[[75]][[3]][[2]][[4]] = TRUE

print(body(f)[[77]])
# if (dendrogram %in% c("both", "column")) {
#   plot(ddc, axes = FALSE, xaxs = "i", leaflab = "none")
# } else plot.new()
body(f)[[77]][[3]][[2]][[3]] = TRUE

f(x)
```

[image]